# NodeJS Global, JSdom, Unit test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jsdom

This is a hopefully simple question:

When I use to create a dom with jsdom:

```
const dom = (html = '<!doctype html><body></body></html>') => {
  const domObject = new JSDOM(html);
  const { window } = domObject;
  const { document } = (domObject).window;

  global.window = window;
  global.document = document;
  global.navigator = {
    userAgent: 'JSDOM',
    language: 'en'
  };
}

module.exports = dom;
```

and then use it on a test like such:

```
import test from 'tape';
import dom from 'dom';

// To create global dom
dom();
```

and yet when i do a test i have document, window and navigator undefined in tests.
It's really strange, am i missing something? or am I making assumption on it's behavior. Should I approach this differently? If so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is how it's done!

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html

Worked beautifully, for those who are curious.